# I can't figure out what is wrong with this racket code, I am not able to run it

Tags: racket

This is the code I want to run and I have hardcoded some examples for demonstration purposes, but the code throws the below error and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
#lang racket/gui

(define frame (new frame% [label "London Transport Planner"] [width 400] [height 300]))

(define text-start (new text-field% [parent frame] [label "Start:"] [min-width 200]))
(define text-destination (new text-field% [parent frame] [label "Destination:"] [min-width 200]))
(define text-time (new text-field% [parent frame] [label "Time:"] [min-width 200]))
(define text-date (new text-field% [parent frame] [label "Date:"] [min-width 200]))

(define route-type (new choice% [parent frame] [label "Route Type:"] [choices '("Suggested" "Cheapest" "Fastest")]))

(define check-delays (new check-box% [parent frame] [label "Receive Delay Notifications"]))
(define check-events (new check-box% [parent frame] [label "Receive Event Suggestions"]))

(define button-plan (new button% [parent frame] [label "Plan Route"] [callback (lambda (button event)
                                                                                (plan-route))]))

(define (plan-route)
  (define start (send text-start get-value))
  (define destination (send text-destination get-value))
  (define time (send text-time get-value))
  (define date (send text-date get-value))
  (define type (send route-type get-string-selection))
  (define delays? (send check-delays get-value))
  (define events? (send check-events get-value))

  ; Hard-coded example routes for demonstration purposes
  (define suggested-route (if (equal? type "Suggested")
                             "Suggested Route: A -> B -> C"
                             ""))
  (define cheapest-route (if (equal? type "Cheapest")
                             "Cheapest Route: X -> Y -> Z"
                             ""))
  (define fastest-route (if (equal? type "Fastest")
                             "Fastest Route: P -> Q -> R"
                             ""))

  (define event-suggestion (if events?
                               "Event suggestion: Visit Museum at X"
                               ""))


  (define result-frame (new frame% [label "Route Details"] [width 400] [height 200]))
  (define result-text (new text% [parent result-frame] [label ""])) ;

  (send result-text set-value (string-append suggested-route "\n" cheapest-route "\n" fastest-route "\n" event-suggestion))
  (send result-frame show #t))

(send frame show #t)
```

and this is the error I am getting,

```
instantiate: unused initialization arguments
  unused arguments:
   [parent (object:frame% ...)]
   [label ""]
  instantiated class name: text%
```

Tried using this solution but it doesn't work either. To fix this error, I removed the [parent result-frame] and [label ""] arguments, as they are not needed for the text% class.

```
(define (plan-route)
  (define start (send text-start get-value))
  (define destination (send text-destination get-value))
  (define time (send text-time get-value))
  (define date (send text-date get-value))
  (define type (send route-type get-string-selection))
  (define delays? (send check-delays get-value))
  (define events? (send check-events get-value))

  ; Hard-coded example routes for demonstration purposes
  (define suggested-route (if (equal? type "Suggested")
                             "Suggested Route: A -> B -> C"
                             ""))
  (define cheapest-route (if (equal? type "Cheapest")
                             "Cheapest Route: X -> Y -> Z"
                             ""))
  (define fastest-route (if (equal? type "Fastest")
                             "Fastest Route: P -> Q -> R"
                             ""))

  (define event-suggestion (if events?
                               "Event suggestion: Visit Museum at X"
                               ""))

  ; Display the results in a new window
  (define result-frame (new frame% [label "Route Details"] [width 400] [height 200]))
  (define result-text (new text% [parent result-frame]))
  (send result-text set-value (string-append suggested-route "\n" cheapest-route "\n" fastest-route "\n" event-suggestion))
  (send result-frame show #t))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use `define` inside `define`- `define` creates global variables and there is no need to define `start`, `destination` and so on globally- you should use [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29) here, which creates local variables.

[`text%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html) class doesn't have `parent` or `label` arguments. If you want to display some text, you have to use a different type of widget- [`message%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/message_.html) or [`editor-canvas%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/editor-canvas_.html).

Message:

```
(new message%
     [parent result-frame]
     [label (string-append suggested-route "\n"
                           cheapest-route "\n"
                           fastest-route "\n"
                           event-suggestion)])
```

Editor-canvas:

```
(define text (new text%))
(define editor-canvas (new editor-canvas%
                           [parent result-frame]
                           [editor text]))
(send text insert (string-append suggested-route "\n"
                                 cheapest-route "\n"
                                 fastest-route "\n"
                                 event-suggestion))
```

Comment: `define` inside `define` creates local lexically scoped variables, and is encouraged in Racket; see https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Definitions%29